# How can I display a facebook feed on my website?

Tags: facebook, integration

I am trying to display my 3 most recent status updates from facebook in my website. I've seen this article (http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/how-to-display-facebook-statuses-on-wordpress-blog/) on displaying the facebook feed in wordpress however my site is just a regular website using html/css. If anyone can shed some light on this that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Is this still something you're dealing with?  Or can this question be closed?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly...There is an easy way to embed the actual facebook feed. Theres a tutorial and Download on http://fourgefeed.com .If you have any problems just contact the admin. He is more then happy to help.